# Mail client wouldn't connect with my Docker mail server

Tags: docker, postfix-mta, mail-server, dovecot, ispconfig

I've build a Docker based "Perfect server" clone of [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-debian-10-nginx-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3.1/) tutorial, but more up-to-date and I succeeded at sending and receiving emails locally via the Roundcube webmail application towards external email accounts without using external relays. However, I cannot figure out why connections between mail clients and the mailserver continiously fail.

First of all, my docker-compose.yml file globally contains:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
mailserver:
 container_name: mailserver
 image: mailserver:latest
 build: .
 restart: on-failure
 hostname: ${HOSTNAME}
 domainname: ${DOMAIN}
 ports:
  - 80:80
  - 25:25 
  - 143:143
  - 465:465 
  - 587:587 
  - 993:993 
  - 995:995
 environment:
  - HOSTNAME=mail
  - DOMAIN=localhost
  - MYSQL_HOST=localhost
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
 networks: 
  - default

networks:
 default-network:
  driver: bridge
```

Recently, I build another image containing a standalone mailserver existing out of Postfix, Dovecot, Roundcube, PhpMyAdmin and Apache since I wanted to test differences about why those connections between the mailserver and mail-clients fail.

For that, I pretty much installed all dependencies, and changed some Postfix values like:

```
postconf -e myhostname="${HOSTNAME}"
postconf -e mydomain="${DOMAIN}"
postconf -e mydestination="${HOSTNAME}, localhost.${DOMAIN}, localhost, ${DOMAIN}"
postconf -e mynetworks="127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128"
```

For the last image, I've just followed [this](https://www.tecmint.com/setup-postfix-mail-server-and-dovecot-with-mariadb-in-centos/) tutorial to the point where it should connect Thunderbird to the mailserver.

**NOTE**: The reason I'm using (and testing with) ports 143 and 25, but will not use them in final form.

But the same thing as the "Perfect server" -image occurred, which is that the client couldn't connect to the mailserver.

Meanwhile while building that image, I launched a virtual machine (same domain, ip address and network) without using containers (Debian 10) by following the exact same tutorial (Perfect server). And in the end, I succeeded the connection with Outlook/Thunderbird (again over the same ports).

So I came to the conclusion that I'm missing something that solves the issue about the reason why Docker containers prevent/block those connections even when ports are open and DNS records are set.

**Question**: what am I doing wrong/why do mail clients fail connections towards the mailserver while being inside a Docker container?

Perfect server based Docker image for reference: https://github.com/jerob/docker-ispconfig

Answer (score 0):

Kind of stupid, port 143 was closed within the container itself (figured it out with nmap -p port:domain). That solved this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).